# Cannot use Apache Commons FileUpload with Spring Boot multipart.resolve-lazily

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, streaming, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm building a REST API using Spring Boot framework. There is one endpoint where users will be able to upload a large file (~1GB). I'm using [Streaming API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html) from Apache Commons FileUpload.

I only want to enable streaming only at that endpoint. Therefore, I configure my Spring Boot as follow:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled = true
spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily = true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size = 2GB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size = 2GB
```

And here is my endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/import", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> importData(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, FileUploadException {
    System.out.println("Streaming...");

    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    if (!isMultipart) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator iterStream = upload.getItemIterator(request);
    while (iterStream.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Iterating...");

        FileItemStream item = iterStream.next();

        if (!item.isFormField()) {

            String name = item.getFieldName();
            System.out.println("Field name is: " + name);

            try (InputStream uploadedStream = item.openStream();
                 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("file.zip")) {

                IOUtils.copy(uploadedStream, out);
            }

        } else {

            try (InputStream stream = item.openStream()) {
                String formFieldName = item.getFieldName();
                String formFieldValue = Streams.asString(stream);
                System.out.println(String.format("Form field found - %s: %s", formFieldName, formFieldValue));
            }
        }
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Data streamed successfully.");
}
```

The method is called and the code is executed. However, the `FileItemIterator` is empty, there for the `while` loop is not executed.

This code works perfectly if I set `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled = false`. But I don't want to do that because as I said, I don't want to disable Spring Boot Multipart Resolver globally, but only at this endpoint.

So, what is wrong with my code? Why is the `FileItemIterator` is empty?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I think the problem is at Spring `StandardServletMultipartResolver`. When I switch to `CommonsMultipartResolver` (as configured below), my code works perfectly.

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setResolveLazily(true);
    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not resolve the issue for me. iterStream.hasNext() returns false from the beginning. I am using some Interceptors and Spring Security which maybe mess with the request before it reaches my controller. In your case, did you also have Spring Security and e.g. a LocaleChangeInterceptor in use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have Spring Security but no interceptor.

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that by disabling the interceptors, hasNext() has begun returning true. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: To disable an interceptor for a specific URL, do this: @Override
public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {  registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/the/endpoint/you/use/for/upload");
}

Comment: I'm getting No primary or single unique constructor found for interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest. Any idea why ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any experience with that error yet.